# Mint4win -- persistency

Tags: windows, linux, linux-mint

I installed Linux mint 14 using the mint4win application as an apllication inside windows. After that I rebooted into the mint OS. then I installed python idle 2.7 and some other softwares. Then I rebooted into mint again. And to my surprise, all of this was gone and I have to install everything again.

What the hell is going on? Is there no other way except installing on hard drive so as to retain changes?

I tried installing on a flash drive but that was insanely slow and I immediately formatted the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the Mint4Win installer is just part of the process. After it reboots into the Mint Live system, on the desktop there should be an icon titled **Install Linux Mint**. Run that to perform the regular Mint installation. On completion your PC will reboot again and now you can use the persistent Mint system and changes won't be lost across reboots.

Comment: Sir, I installed mint on the desktop but now i am facing a new problem. Please see: [Cinnamon installation](http://superuser.com/questions/568118/cinnamon-installation)