# Cinnamon installation

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I installed the Linux Mint 14 32-bit MATE version on my desktop yesterday. Now I want Cinnamon.

Though I thought of installing the CINNAMON version instead of the MATE version the USB of CINNAMON version was not getting started properly.

I tried to install cinnamon from the menu search but at the last step it says that some packages could not be installed.

I want to know why this is happenning and the solution to this.

Comment: Any specific error messages?

Comment: You may post the way you solved the issue in an answer to your own question and accept your own answer!

Comment: Yes. Sir. I will soon do that.